# how do I resolve "please commit your changes or stash before you merge" when I have no local changes

Tags: git

I am trying to run my script in a python project but everytime i try to it keeps saying "Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge." "Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge"

I have not changed any of my files. I have already tried:

**git reset --hard**

**git checkout -t -f remote/branch**

**git checkout filename**

**git restore .**

I have no idea what else to do. I literally have no changes....this is VSCode if it matters!

edit:
when i do git status , I have only one untracked file ( " / " ) that comes up

Comment: _Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge_ That is not all it says. What are some of the files? _I have only one untracked file ( " / " )_ That sounds bad. You may need to stop thrashing _now_ before you screw something up.

Comment: what do you mean? @matt I am just trying to run a script, but I can't because of my "files" that i changed, but i dont have any local changes.

Comment: If you want help, help us to help you. Give information! Perhaps it would help us if you showed us the script? Perhaps it would help us if you told us the rest of the message about "the following files"? Perhaps it would help us if you showed us the console conversation with Git?

Comment: @AkiBad There is an untracked file, so you need to address that. Do you really want to delete it? If not, please [see my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77017995/19580559).

Comment: @AkiBad You should really stop trying random commands like `git reset --hard` if you don't know what they do. Otherwise, you could cause a lot more frustration for yourself in the future when you are on a completely different blob or end up deleting your changes...

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to either **stage** or **ignore** that untracked file.

If you want to ignore it, then edit your `.gitignore` file and write the name of your file.

To stage it, simply stage as you normally would (`git add -A` to stage all will do the trick since it is your only change anyway). Then, you can run `git commit` and you'll be on a clean working directory.